# What does the terminolgy 'open bar' mean when selecting board type upon booking hotel room?

Tags: bookings, hotels, terminology

I would like to know what the terminology 'open bar' means when on the booking breakdown page/ selecting room type. For more context it is under the column 'board basis' and next to the words 'bed and breakfast'.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As terminology frequently varies by locale, please [edit] your post to indicate which booking site you are using and where the hotel is located; *board basis* is not terminology used in North America, for example, so what I think of as "open bar" may not be applicable.

Comment: If you can just link directly to the page, that would really help.

Comment: "Open bar" normally means "drinks are free", but that's a really unusual feature for a hotel (except all inclusive resorts).